# How do i randomize between labels when button is pressed?

Tags: swift, random, label, uilabel

I'm pretty new to swift. The purpose of my app is to show different text on my labels when a button is pressed. I will have hundreds of labels so should i use some kind of a database. If so how can I randomize between these labels. Would be great if any of you could write that piece of code. I also need my app to remember the previous label, so that a user can go back when another button is pressed.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: https://learnappmaking.com/random-numbers-swift/

Comment: @Ollesoder Do you need a random text should be set to all labels when a button is pressed ?
Can you bit more clear with your explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to generate a random number in Swift:

```
let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(x))
```

This generates a random number between 0 and x-1.

Unfortunately, without a more detailed description and without your code, I can't answer anything more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `array` of all the possible `labels`, i.e.

```
let labels = ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4"]
//add data to the labels
```

Use **`randomElement()`** on the `labels` `array` to get a `randomLabel`, i.e.

```
let randomLabel = labels.randomElement()
```

Comment: Create an outlet of the lable in the controller and set its text property to randomLabel, i.e. yourLabel.text = randomLabel

Answer (score 0):

You can do create an Array with labels. For example:

```
 let labels = ["Some Text","Some Text","Some Text"]
```

Then use randomElement() from labels array:

```
randomTextLabel.text = labels.randomElement()
```

You can also use json to store data. I dont know how, but you can always google!